# Visual Flow Picklist Choice Value does not map to Picklist value on record

Tags: picklist, visual-workflow

I have created a Visual Flow that allows a user to create a Case record in Salesforce. On this Flow I have Checkboxes, Text fields and Picklists. All are mapped accordingly to the records that they are supposed to create on the Case record. The Dropdown list on the Flow is mapped to the Picklist field on the Case object.

The checkboxes and text fields update accordingly through the Flow, but the Picklist values on the Flow do not update the record. Can anyone help with this? I have read that Dynamic Choices can be used to work around this but I still cannot get this to work. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have contacted Salesforce support regarding the issue and it has been resolved. Go to the Explorer tab and go to each Choice and in the 'Stored Value' enter the exact name of the label (the label must match the picklist value on the record). Ie. If the label is 'Email', type 'Email' into the Stored Value. Salesforce will prompt you to click email which will insert '{!Email}' but this will not work. The brackets must be removed in order for the picklist to be updated with with the Stored Value.

Also note that the picklist fields in the Flow must be mapped on a 'Record Update' and will not work with a 'Record Create'.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic Choices are designed to pull multiple RECORDS, not multiple picklist values. So unfortunately that won't help you. :(

I can think of no reason why this wouldn't map, however. I know it's not terribly helpful, but I would log a Salesforce ticket and see what they say. Can't hurt.

In the meantime, double-check you've got the right field name and all that due diligence stuff. I can't tell you how many times I've hit a problem like this, only to find out it's be

Comment: I have discovered that a record update allows for the updating of picklist values through the Flow. I am still having issues updating the actual criteria from the Flow to the Case object.